# Missing corrupted external SSD

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I have an external SSD that has become corrupted due to writing files while the Mac feel asleep. There's nothing important on the drive, so I'm not worried about any data loss.

My problem is that the macs I have don't seem to recognize the disk when it's plugged in. It doesn't show up in Disk Utility. And it doesn't show up in terminal with `diskutil list`.

The Hardware itself is all fine. This isn't the first time this has happened. It's the second. - The only way I could figure out how to fix it the first time was to plug it into a friends Windows PC and have him reformat it for me. But I'm looking for a way to do it myself, on a mac.

- Running up to date Big Sur
- SSD is formatted for APFS

---

Update 1:

Spent the morning reformatting the drive. Took about 30 attempts before it was recognized on a PC. But reformatted it, and then it was able to be recognized by macOS again. Less than 5 minutes later however, it lost connection while being used and is currently again not able to connect.

I'm trying to find a different enclosure to see if it's enclosure of SSD that is the issue. Although both are brand new.

Comment: In Disk Utility are you using the Device view [Cmd/2] or the volume view [Cmd/1]?

Comment: When you say "This is the second time", do you mean the second time that this drive has become corrupted, or the second time that the Mac has corrupted a drive? A Mac can't fall asleep while it's writing files. Even closing the lid while copying should not cause corruption. 
If more than one Mac fails to recognise the drive, then I'd say the problem was with the drive. I would not continue to trust a drive that can't be recognized and which has 'corrupted', possibly twice.

Comment: Did you correctly unmount the drive, or assume because the Mac was asleep it would be OK to skip that step?

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't appear in device view or volume view. And it doesn't appear in terminal either. - I didn't unmount the device. When I turned on the monitor it gave me a notification that the device had been unmounted. -  I've added some more information to the question too.

Comment: @benwiggy This was the second time time the drive ended up corrupted and unable to be found in Disk Utility. I assumed it was due to the mac going to sleep. But it seems like it may be an issue with the enclosure or SSD. Both of which are brand new, which is why I thought it was the Macs fault. I just updated the question with some more information though after it's happened a third time.

Comment: Your update does indicate a hardware issue - whether the drive itself, the enclosure or even just the cable, I think you'll have to experiment to discover. Wish you luck :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! I'll see what happens... as soon as I can find a new enclosure!

Comment: Does it even connect and remain connected to the Mac? Top left menu bar: Apple, Option key, System Information and look under USB.

Comment: @Gilby it sees it there under thunderbolt. It appears to be the SSD. I’m waiting until tomorrow morning when the manufacturer opens to do troubleshooting with them and should then find out for sure